Jest & Vue Testing UseHead inside Computed
Trying to test UseHead in my component that's inside of a computed but it is throwing the following error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
Vue Component has
useHead(computed(() => ({
  title: data?.title,
})));

Jest Test
import { useHead } from '@unhead/vue';

jest.mock('@unhead/vue');

const expectedArguments = { title: 'Test Title' };

describe('Page Meta Tests', () => {
  it('should display meta title', async () => {
     const wrapper = await mountComponent();
     expect(useHead).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedArguments);
  });
});


what line of code is the error on?  there is no name in the code shown

Can you share the way you mocked @unhead/vue? Also the we don't know what mountComponent function looks like, you might have to attach the component to the virtual dom

You should not mock useHead just to test if it has been called. Just test the actual behavior of a testing component.
it('should display meta title', async () => {
     const wrapper = await mountComponent();
     expect(document.title).toBe(expectedTitle);
  });

